# Surface Area of a Region inside a Region

Tags: regions, mesh

I need to find the surface area of a region which is within another region. The regions I'm working with are fairly complex and so I'm looking for a general solution, but I'll use a cylinder and tetrahedron as an example.

Lets say I have the following regions:

```
Container = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1];
MyRegion = Tetrahedron[{{0, 2, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2.5}}];
```

I want to find the surface area of `MyRegion` which is contained by `Container`The way I imagined doing this was using `RegionIntersection`, finding a boundary mesh, and then using `Area`. Then I would need to somehow figure out what area of the intersection is not in common with the boundary of `MyRegion`, but I'm not sure how to approach that or if that is even the best method. Any suggestions?

Edit:

My code generates a function that is used in an implicit region - so its not always the same. I've included a sample one below (sorry - I was trying to avoid posting such a large function). Technically I'm just interested in the surface area, but as I have it, the ImplicitRegion it will be a volume.

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=0.564936 Log[(
   6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + y)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - Abs[0. + x])^2] + 
   2 Abs[0. + x])/(-6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + y)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - 
        Abs[0. + x])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + x])] + 
    0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + y)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - 
        Abs[0. + x])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + x])/(-6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + y)^2 + 
    (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + x])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + x])] - 
    0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((0. + y)^2 + (0. + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - 
        Abs[0. + x])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + x])/(-6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((0. + y)^2 + 
    (0. + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + x])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + x])] + 
    0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - 
        Abs[0. + y])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + y])/(-6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + 
    (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + y])] + 
    0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - 
        Abs[0. + y])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + y])/(-6.2 + 
    2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + (-1.67 + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 
    2 Abs[0. + y])] - 0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + 
    (0. + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + y])/(-6.2 + 
    2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + (0. + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 
    2 Abs[0. + y])] - 0.564936 Log[(6.2 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + 
    (0. + z)^2)^2 + (-3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 2 Abs[0. + y])/(-6.2 + 
    2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + (0. + z)^2)^2 + (3.1 - Abs[0. + y])^2] + 
    2 Abs[0. + y])] + 0.564936 Log[(1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 +
    (-3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (-0.755 - Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])/
    (-1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + (-3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (0.755 - Abs[-0.915 +   
    z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])] + 0.564936 Log[(1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + 
    (-3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (-0.755 - Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])/
    (-1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + (-3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (0.755 - 
        Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])] + 0.564936 Log[(
   1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + (3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (-0.755 - Abs[-0.915 + z])^2]   + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])/(-1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((-3.1 + x)^2 + (3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (0.755 - 
        Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])] + 0.564936 Log[(
   1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + (3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (-0.755 - 
   Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])/(-1.51 + 2 Sqrt[((3.1 + x)^2 + 
   (3.1 + y)^2)^2 + (0.755 - Abs[-0.915 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.915 + z])] - 
 0.564936 Log[(1.67 + 2 Sqrt[((0. + x)^2 + (0. + y)^2)^2 + (-0.835 - 
 Abs[-0.835 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.835 + z])/(-1.67 + 2 Sqrt[((0. + x)^2 
 + (0. + y)^2)^2 + (0.835 - Abs[-0.835 + z])^2] + 2 Abs[-0.835 + z])];

MyRegion=ImplicitRegion[f[x, y, z] >=  5, {{x, -5.3, 5.3}, {y, -5.3, 5.3}, {z, 0, 1.67}}]

Container=Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,1.67}},5.3]
```

Comment: In principle, you could just do `Area[RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary[myRegion], container]]`, but I'm not near a Mathematica instance right now to try it out and I recall it having trouble with intersections of regions of different dimensionalities.

Comment: @Rahul Like you said, it doesn't quite work since `RegionBoundary[MyRegion]` is of a different dimension than `Container`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, one possibility is to decompose the surface of the `Tetrahedron` into four triangles, intersect each with `Container`, compute the `Area` of the resulting planar objects, and sum them.

```
Area[RegionIntersection[Polygon[#], Container]] & /@ 
  Subsets[{{0, 2, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2.5}}, {3}] // Total
(* 7.98614 *)
```

**Generalization to an ImplicitRegion**

The preceding toy problem could be solved without much difficulty, because the solid `Tetrahedron` could be replaced by a set of surfaces.  As noted in the  comment below, the OP would like to compute the area of a truncated `ImplicitFunction`.  If it can be represented as a surface,

```
ImplicitFuncton[f[x, y, x] == 0, {x, y, z}]];
```

then the `Area` of `f` inside the cylinder given in the Question is

```
Area[ImplicitFuncton[f[x, y, x] == 0 && x^2 + y^2 < 1 && 2 > z > 0, {x, y, z}]]]
```

As an example,

```
Area[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4 == 0 && x^2 + y^2 < 1 && 2 > z > 0, {x, y, z}]]
(* -4 (-2 + Sqrt[3]) π *)
```

**DiscretizeRegion for Complex Regions**

Consider a more complex surface, taken for the Applications section of the `ImplicitRegion` documentation.  If it is truncated by a cylinder,

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x^6 - 5 x^4 y z + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 z + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 z + 
  y^6 + z^6 - 1 == 0 && x^2 + y^2 < 1 && 1.2 > z > .8, {x, y, z}];
```

then `Area[r]` returns unevaluated.  However, `DiscretizeRegion` combined with `NIntegrate` works well.

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[r]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ dr]
(* 3.1817 *)
```

The just added function in the question can be handled similarly.

```
MyRegion = ImplicitRegion[
   f[x, y, z] == 5, {{x, -5.3, 5.3}, {y, -5.3, 5.3}, {z, 0, 1.67}}] ;
dmr = DiscretizeRegion[MyRegion]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ dmr]
(* 25.1979 *)
```

By the way, sometimes decreasing `MaxCellMeasure` improves integration accuracy by more finely zoning the surface.  For instance,

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[r, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> .01}]
```

improves discretization of the first surface in this section, slightly correcting its area to `3.18411`.

Comment: In reality, I need a more general method since I use complicated Implicit Regions rather than tetrahedrons. Also, I'm trying to understand how what you did works. I tried the following hoping to get 3.14, but it returned 0. Do you know why?

Area[RegionIntersection[Polygon[{{3, 0, 0}, {-2, -2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]]

Comment: @BenP1192  A `Sphere` is hollow.  Use `Ball` instead.

Comment: @BenP1192  I and others need to know more about your `ImplicitRegion`s.  Must they be volumes, or, can they be surfaces?  In any case, please provide a sample in Mathematica format.

Comment: My problem with this solution is that I believe it still includes the area of the top portion of the region. I need to find the area only where f==5, but limited by a container. This means that the region of which I need the surface area is not necessarily a closed region. In this case, the upper bound would be left open. Does that make sense? It's a little difficult to describe.

Comment: Nevermind. I wasn't seeing the picture clearly. You're correct, thanks!

Comment: @BenP1192  This was an interest Question, and I learned a lot answering it.  Also, thanks for accepting the answer.  Best wishes.